# Implementing a C-style sizeof() function in D

Tags: d, sizeof, ctfe

I'd like to implement a C-style sizeof() function in D. (I know about the .sizeof thing, but it's to help in porting a lot of C (C99).)

I want it to be able to run at compile-time, obviously and take a type or an expression as an argument. Ideally, I'd like it to have the same syntax as C, if at all possible, rather than use the distinctive template invocation syntax, as that would greatly increase its utility. Is this at all possible?

Comment: size_t sizeof( T )( T x ) { return T.sizeof; } // is an abject failure - my first, doomed attempt

Comment: size_t sizeof( T )() { return T.sizeof; }
    size_t sizeof( T )( T x) { return T.sizeof; }

  // So’s this.

Comment: btw do you know this guide? http://dlang.org/ctod.html

Comment: Yes, I went right through that part of the site. I'm still very much a newcomer though. I'm currently re-reading Ali Çehreli's online book, extremely helpful. Shame the examples are a bit ropey and unrealistic, but there's only so much you can do in a tutorial when you need to maintain brevity and concentrate on the feature you're intending to showcase.

Comment: While it's still WIP, the DLang Tour also has some material to offer, e.g. http://tour.dlang.io/tour/en/gems/compile-time-function-evaluation-ctfe

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want a behavior similar to the `size` function below?
`size2` would be a runtime function, which of course is a bit pointless in D. However you can still get the value from `size2` at CT with `enum val = size2(2 + 2);`. Does this help you?

```d
template size(T)
{
    enum size = T.sizeof;
}

// for expressions
template size(alias T)
{
    enum size = T.sizeof;
}

auto size2(T)(T x)
{
    return T.sizeof;
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    import std.stdio : writeln;

    writeln(size!int); // 4
    writeln(size!long); // 8
    writeln(size!(1 + 1)); // 4


    writeln(size2(2));  // 4
    writeln(size2(2L)); // 8
    writeln(size2(2 + 2)); // 4
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's certainly a worthwhile advancement. I would still need to try getting rid of the ! where it's required for invocation. Second thing is, is sizeof a reserved word in D? Could I actually call a function or template simply "sizeof"? Not essential, as when porting C a global search-and-replace of sizeof( with size2( or whatever is not too onerous.

Comment: I'd like to mark this as "an answer", but I'm not even sure an answer to my wish for the moon on a stick actually exists. Well, to be far an authoritative "no way" is definitely an answer. Perhaps I should simply bribe Walter Bright! :-)

Comment: Is your function really a non-compile-time function?

Comment: I'll play around with your excellent suggestion later on when my hands are not hurting quite so badly.

Comment: > Second thing is, is sizeof a reserved word in D? Could I actually call a function or template simply "sizeof"?

No, I just picked `size2` to make it clearer.

Comment: does anyone think that sizeof(uint), say, is doable, or impossible? Votes one way or the other? (As greenify has an ideal solution in size2() for expressions, I'm just lacking a solution for an argument that is a typename.)

Comment: > Is your function really a non-compile-time function? 

`size2` is a templated function as the the ones you were proposing (it's exactly the same, btw). D will infer T at CT, but _not_ execute the function, except one specifically ask for it. As said I am still not sure what whether this is what you are looking for.

Comment: btw if you already think about applying regexps, why not directly for `sizeof(uint)` -> `uint.sizeof`?

Comment: Good point about regex. That's where I'll have to go if plan A fails, no doubt. I still like the idea of bribing Walter bright. This is a silly incompatibility with C, where C wasn't broken and having to require your brain/fingers is painful for no benefit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121321/discussion-between-cecil-ward-and-greenify).